# Immediate 1-line magic method call on new PHP object

Tags: php, oop, magic-function

I'd like to immediately call a magic method (`__call()`) on a newly constructed object. Example:

```
class Foo {
    public function __call($method,$args) {
        echo "You were looking for the method $method.\n";
    }
}
```

Ideal (but gets a parse error):

```
$foo = new Foo()->bar(); // Fails :(
```

Working:

```
$foo = new Foo();
$foo = $foo->bar();
```

Is this possible? I know PHP 5.4 brought immediate 1-line object method calling (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php) so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

Comment: Do you want the value of `$foo` to be a new instance of the `Foo` class or the return result from the method `bar`?

Comment: Result from method `bar`. @complex857 has a working answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually only missing a `()` pair, this works:

```
$foo = (new Foo())->bar(); // this works.
```

In the PHP 5.4 changelog it writes:

> Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. **(** new
>   Foo **)**->bar().

Comment: Yes, [i have](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GJEa2F). Are you sure you are on php 5.4?

Comment: "Well there's your problem" - Jamie Hyneman

My bad, thank you!